# Why my Raspberry Pi (first version) not boot?

Tags: raspbian, boot-issues

I have one Raspberry Pi (first version). I downloaded Raspbian and NOOBS from official Raspberry's site.

I use **SDFormatter** for format my SD cards and **win32writer** for write *.img file.

When I connect my Raspberry, I can view only first boot informations, after Raspbian auto login I can't view anything.

*Note: I use one microSD with the adapter. Can be a problem?*

Can you help me please?

Thanks

Comment: Do you see any errors before going blank? Also, try using [win32diskimager](http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager) and let us know if it makes any difference. On a sidenote, do do you have anything connected on the USB ports during startup?

Comment: Hi. Sorry I used win32diskimager. I attached online one mouse but I tried whitout it. No errors occurs during boot...

Comment: Are you trying to install Raspbian (which is an image) or NOOBS which is not?

Comment: try a fresh downloaded image without any changes. maybe there is a issue on autologin?

Answer (score 1):

Let understand the problem..

You said you downloaded the Raspbian and NOOBS from the official site" for me that's bit confusing..

You just need to download NOOBS, unzip the files in a folder and copy all the content in the formatted SD card. Then power on the Pi- (but before you power on, make sure you insert the SD card properly and are having a keyboard mouse and Monitor connected to the Pi and then power on the pi).

Note: NOOBS - stands for New out of the box software

Because you have the NOOBS software (unzipped) in the SD card, so when you power on the Pi, after initial configuration the first screen you should get is the list of OS that are available in NOOBS for installation (see below).
[image: NOOB screen on the first boot]

So now from the list of OS available you need to select Raspbian ( or any other OS, based on your need to start the OS installation) -  you need your keyboard or mouse you select the appropriate OS and that you can see on the screen if you are connected to Monitor.

Note: you don't need to download Raspbian separately..

Hope this help

(i would recommend the keyboard and the mouse to be connected.. to the powered USB hub)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me that you are not configured to boot into Desktop. You are sitting at the command line.

Correct?

Something like:

```
 user@raspberrypi:~$
```

If that be the case, run "raspi-config". Type this:

```
 sudo raspi-config
```

Arrow down to "3" which is "Boot Options", press "enter" and set your rpi to
something like "B4 Desktop Autologin Desktop GUI, automatically logged in as 'pi' user". Tab to "Ok" then tab to "Finish", Your rpi will reboot. Maybe this will help.

-Jason

Comment: Author said "after Raspbian auto login".

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but I cannot view command line! After initial boot I view only one black screen.

Comment: What do you plugged into your USB ports, anything?

Answer (score 0):

You downloaded NOOBS from:

https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/NOOBS_latest

?

It's possible that you have a corrupted SD card?

I recommend you just formatting your SD card using the Windows format utility back to Windows FAT32. Then write your image using win32diskimager.

Maybe that will correct any possible bad partitioning and formatting that might be going on.

Good Luck!

-Jason

Comment: Hi, I followed your instructions. I tried to connect only sd card and power cable (without HDMI and Others periperals) I noted that now ACT LED comes on intermittently, can be a power problem?

Answer (score 0):

Go ahead and plug up your HDMI cable to verify video output. I'm assuming you had a standard keyboard plugged into one USB port and a USB mouse in another?

When it comes to power, I recommend an USB power adapter that can output 5v 1Amp. Maybe yours reads 5v 1000ma.

Answer (score 0):

I had a nightmare with the microSD cards on this, they don't seem to contact as well and caused lots of glitches and fails to read cards I just wrote.  Dust seems to get trapped in them so you might try blowing them out with computer duster.    Two cards in one night for me, gave up and used the regular SD card instead.  Those have been unreliable for me for years and it might be worth getting something a bit better for the Pi.  My 2 bits.